# Javascript: How do I expand a user selection based on html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Le Code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/frf7w/12/

So right now, the current method will take the selected text exactly as... selected, and add tags so that when it is displayed, the page doesn't blow up.

But what I want to do:
Is to, when a user selects a portion of a page, if there are un-matched tags within the selection, the selection will either jump forward or backward (depending on what unmatched tag is in the selection) to the tag(s) that make the selection valid html.

The reason why I want to do this, is because I want a user to be able te select text on a page, and be able to edit that text in a WYSIWYG editor (I can currently do this with the linked code), and then put what they've edited back into the page (currently can't do this, because the method I use adds tags).

Comment: I see you are adding a div around your selection, once it is added, do you think you could get this div's parent, and then select it? You may end up with a weird behaviour, however.

Comment: That div is just for displaying the selected text. The selected text itself has no div added. =\

Comment: So, selecting the parent of that div, would likely select the entire page.

Comment: So you basically want to select text, append it to an editor div, then when the user is done editing , paste it directly into the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the boundaries of the selection by [adding a range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/addRange):

```
var sel = window.getSelection(),
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

var startEl = sel.anchorNode;
if (startEl != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
    while (startEl.parentNode != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
        startEl = startEl.parentNode;
    }
}
var endEl = sel.focusNode;
if (endEl != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
    while (endEl.parentNode != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
        endEl = endEl.parentNode;
    }
}

range.setStartBefore(startEl);
range.setEndAfter(endEl);

sel.addRange(range);
```

The above example will give you a selection that is expanded to cover the entire of the tree between the start and end nodes, inclusive (thanks to [`commonAncestorContainer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer)).

This treats text nodes as equal to dom elements, but this shouldn't be a problem for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nq6hr/2/

Comment: is this cross-browser, as in IE7+ and then real browsers?

Comment: I've tested in Chrome 14, FF7, IE9.  I think IE only brought in support for the `range` object from version 9

Comment: good enough. Will give me an excuse to give my boss another reason to suggest to our clients to upgrade =D

Comment: Correct, IE9 is the first version of IE with `Range` and `Selection`. All other browsers have had them for ages.

Answer (score 3):

The `coverAll` method in this SO answer has exactly what you want [Use javascript to extend a DOM Range to cover partially selected nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477192/use-javascript-to-extend-a-dom-range-to-cover-partially-selected-nodes/2477306#2477306). For some reason extending `Selection` prototype does not work for me on my chrome, so I extracted the code and substituted `this` with `window.getSelection()`. Final code looks like this:

```
function coverAll() {
    var ranges = [];
    for(var i=0; i<window.getSelection().rangeCount; i++) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(i);
        while(range.startContainer.nodeType == 3
              || range.startContainer.childNodes.length == 1)
            range.setStartBefore(range.startContainer);
        while(range.endContainer.nodeType == 3
              || range.endContainer.childNodes.length == 1)
            range.setEndAfter(range.endContainer);
        ranges.push(range);
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
        window.getSelection().addRange(ranges[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the nodes given by the selection. It seems extentNode and anchorNode represents the end and the beginning of nodes of the selection both can help you having the "full" selection. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/DOM/Selection

For the inline editing you should give a try to contentEditable attribute. You can surround the elements of your selection with a span containing this attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.contentEditable